# Using Outlook Redemption from a Windows Service

Tags: outlook-redemption

I have a Windows Service that I need to access emails, I don't think I can use the Logon method as profiles are not accessible from a Windows Service so I have been using LogonHostedExchangeMailbox with the Username in the Domain\User format, this appears to logon but when I start trying to access methods or properties e.g.  mRDOSession.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)

I receive the following error
Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore: MAPI_E_LOGON_FAILED
ulVersion: 0
Error: The information store could not be opened.
Component: MAPI 1.0
ulLowLevelError: 0
ulContext: 646

I have outlook 2016 installed and Exchange 2019

Comment: Does your Exchange server have basic authentication enabled

Comment: Yes we have basic authentication enabled

Comment: Please send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com, and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.